# Calculate confidence interval for factor levels in r

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a dataset of ~2,204 bird surveys. I calculated detection rate per sex using (number of 1s per sex/total number of surveys per sex). I would like to calculate the confidence interval of the detection rate for each sex. The data set looks like this:

| bird | sex | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | f | 1 |
| a | f | 0 |
| a | f | 1 |
| a | f | 0 |
| a | f | 1 |
| b | m | 1 |
| b | m | 0 |
| b | m | 0 |
| b | m | 1 |
| b | m | 1 |
| c | f | 1 |
| c | f | 0 |
| c | f | 1 |
| c | f | 0 |
| c | f | 1 |

I used this code to calculate detection rate per sex:

```
df$outcome <- as.numeric(df$outcome)
detection_sex <- df %>% 
    group_by(sex) %>% 
   summarise(dr = mean(sex))
```

The detection rate for males is 59% and the detection rate for females is 56%. I am not sure how to extract the 95% CI for each sex. I have 729 surveys for females and 1,475 surveys for males, so I used this code to try to get the 95% CI:

```
Hmisc::binconf(1475, 2204)
```

This produced:

```
PointEst     Lower    Upper
 0.3307623 0.3114294 0.350684
```

That can't be right, as the average detection rate is 59% for males. Is there a way to get the 95% CI of average detection rate for each sex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to compute the confidence interval for detection rates in each sex independently, is that correct?

If so, you could try the following. After grouping by `sex`, you can use `binconf` for binomial probabilities from `Hmisc` and include arguments to give you all the results you need for each `sex`.

When calling `binconf` the first argument will be the total number of detected outcomes (or `sum(outcome)`). The second argument is total number of birds surveyed/observations (or `n()`).

The results include the following (for each `sex`): `X` which is the total number of `outcome`s, `N` for total number of observations, `PointEst` which is the point estimate for mean, and the upper and lower confidence interval estimates.

The default is alpha of 0.05 and Wilson interval.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Hmisc)

df %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise(CI = list(binconf(sum(outcome), 
                              n = n(), 
                              include.x = T, 
                              include.n = T, 
                              return.df = T))) %>%
  unnest(CI)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  sex       X     N PointEst Lower Upper
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 f         6    10      0.6 0.313 0.832
2 m         3     5      0.6 0.231 0.882
```

Comment: This works great. If I attempt to knit the document after adding this code, it says: "Error in unnest(CI): object "CI" not found calls: <Anonymous>...WithCallingHandlers ......." I'm not sure what is causing this.